# How do you prove that there exists a highest element of any finite, nonempty subset of Natural Numbers? Is the following algorithmic proof valid?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, natural-numbers, well-orders

Since the given set, $C \subset \mathbb{N}$ is non empty, hence by well ordering principle there exists $\alpha \in C$ which is the lowest element in C. Also, since the set $C$ is finite, $\quad \exists \beta \in \mathbb{N}| \quad x\le\beta, \quad \forall x\in C $.

Algorithmic proof:
You start from $\beta$ and check whether it belongs to $C$. If it does, then $\beta$ is the highest element in C, else, you go to $\beta -1$ and repeat the process. One only needs to continue this procedure till he or she reaches $\alpha$. If no element of $\mathbb{N}$ greater than $\alpha$ but less than or equal to $\beta$ belongs to $C$, then $\alpha$ will be the highest element of $C$ for we have already established that $\alpha \in C$.

Comment: You should not apply the well ordering principle on $C$ itself (that brings no profit) but on the set $\{\text{upper bounds of }C\}$. That set is not empty because $C$ is finite. Further it can be proved that the smallest element of that set is the highest element of $C$.

Comment: Why may I ask that I not apply the well ordering principle on C? Is the algorithmic proof I used incorrect?

Comment: I must confess that I did not take sufficient notice of your question. I thought it concerned a proof of the fact that $C$ has a greatest element and that your first paragraph on its own was meant to be a proof of that allready (which is not the case). This as an application of the well ordening principle. In my comment I provided a proof based on the well ordening principle and the fact that $C$ has some lowest element plays no part in it. Only the facts $C\neq\varnothing$ and $C$ finite are essential. Further I am not familiar with the concept "algorithmic proof".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your informal algorithmic proof works, but establishing its correctness rigorously will require some form of induction on $\mathbb{N}$, and at that point you're probably better off using a more direct argument like the one suggested by @drhab in the comments.

You can also argue directly by induction on the size of the set. The result is clearly true for sets of size $n=1$. If the result is true for all sets of size $n$ and $C$ has size $n+1$ (where $n\ge 1$), then for any $\alpha\in C$, the largest element of $C$ is $\max(\alpha,\beta)$ where $\beta$ is the largest element of $C-\{\alpha\}$.